# How to force Microsoft Edge to download file using correct file extension?

Tags: wordpress, html, microsoft-edge

I don't know why, but clicking an anchor link to a .themepack file in Edge causes Edge to change the file extension to ".htm" instead, but only on my site. The .themepack files available on the Microsoft gallery do not behave this way.

Given this, I'm sure it must be a server configuration, but I can't determine how to fix it. At first it was trying to display the .themepack (it's a cab format file) as if it was text, right in the browser. I added the html5 attribute "download" to my `<a>` tag and that prompted for download, but it still tries to name it as .htm.

Demo of issue:
https://soulcon.com/downloads contains a link to https://soulcon.com/img/SOULCON.themepack
This either tries to show as text, or if you use the page to click the link containing the "download" attribute, it downloads as a .htm file.

Links at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13768/windows-desktop-themes do not cause this.

Considering this site is on managed wordpress by GoDaddy, I don't have any true direct access to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to associate the `.themepack` file extension with the `application/octet-stream` MIME type on the server. Ask a support person at your hosting provider how to do that. It may be doable with an `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thanks for response. I had tried using a plugin in WordPress and a few mime types like the vnd/ms-compressed-cab type, but I didn't try octet-stream.  It still didn't work (using the plugin or even in the .htaccess file (using http://www.htaccess-guide.com/adding-mime-types as instructions). I think I'll reach out to the host (sadly, GoDaddy).

Answer (score 0):

Worked round the issue by zipping the file.

Comment: So sad you had to zip file. I'm facing the same issue for my own file extension : EDGE changes it to zip.